# method flatMap in class java.util.Optional<T> cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, option-type, flatmap

My code is giving an error in flatmap.

```
public Optional<User> getUserWithAuthorities() {
    return SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().flatMap(UserDao::findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin);
}
```

Below is the error:

```
controller/AuthenticationController.java:[77,51] method flatMap in class java.util.Optional<T> cannot be applied to given types;
       [ERROR]   required: java.util.function.Function<? super java.lang.String,java.util.Optional<U>>
       [ERROR]   found: UserDao::f[...]Login
       [ERROR]   reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) U
       [ERROR]     (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
       [ERROR]       cannot find symbol
       [ERROR]         symbol:   method findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(java.lang.String)
       [ERROR]         location: interface net.javaguides.springboot.dao.UserDao)
```

This is UserDao code:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

    Optional<User> findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(String login);

}
```

This is SecurityUtils code:

```
public final class SecurityUtils {

    private SecurityUtils() {}

    /**
     * Get the login of the current user.
     *
     * @return the login of the current user.
     */
    public static Optional<String> getCurrentUserLogin() {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        return Optional.ofNullable(extractPrincipal(securityContext.getAuthentication()));
    }

    private static String extractPrincipal(Authentication authentication) {
        if (authentication == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
            UserDetails springSecurityUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            return springSecurityUser.getUsername();
        } else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof String) {
            return (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: On what `UserDAO` do you want to call that method?

Comment: `findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin`, is it `SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin()` push the result to `flatmap` right?

Comment: The point is that `findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin` is an **instance** method, and so you need an instance of `UserDAO` to call that method on. It should look something like `flatMap(theUserDaoInstance::findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin)`.

Comment: @Slaw oh, thanks for the help, im gonna check my code

Comment: @Slaw thanks bro, thats the problem

Comment: Yeah, this is why I did ask on which instance you want to call the method on. But turns out - the fact that it is an instance method was the error itself - which I assumed to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the reference to the interface class `UserDao::findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin`. Java cannot call the method using the interface alone.

To solve it, instead refer to an instantiated object of type `UserDao`.

Here's an example implementation of the interface:

```java
    class UserDaoImplementation implements UserDao {
        @Override
        public Optional<User> findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(String login) {
            User user = User.builder().name("Tom").build();
            return Optional.of(user);
        }
    }
```

Then create an instance and reference it instead of the interface class:

```java
    public static Optional<User> getUserWithAuthorities() {
        UserDao userDao = new UserDaoImplementation();
        return SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().flatMap(userDao::findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin);
    }
```

In this case, the `getUserWithAuthorities` method now returns an `Optional` containing a `User` object.